# Unity - Dynamically growing text area from top to bottom

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm making turn-based 2D game and I want to have an in-game UI console which prints every move and is scrollable.

[In inspector](https://i.imgur.com/Y9BhI7V.png), I have main GameObject called Console. In Console, there is Viewport with Rect Mask 2D component and basic Scrollbar. In Viewport I have Content which has Scroll Rect component and also Vertical Layout Group and Content Size Fitter to make it dynamically growing. In Content there is only TextMeshPro which displays text. [This is how it looks in the scene](https://i.imgur.com/hb8Wd37.png).

Everything works fine except that the text itself is [set in the center](https://i.imgur.com/P6qx6p9.png) and I can't move it to the top. It makes the text growing from center to top & bottom at the same time, which is not the effect I expect. This is how it looks [in the scene](https://s11.gifyu.com/images/ScGEm.gif), and [in the game](https://s11.gifyu.com/images/ScGE7.gif) (gifs).

I want to set it to the top and make the text growing only from top to bottom. Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: Is your TMP settings set to middle align the text maybe? (It's the default) see [TMP -> Inspector section E - Alignment](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObjectUIText.html)

Comment: @derHugo Nope, it's set to top left

Comment: Just to confirm can you show the full Inspector of the TMP component?

Comment: @derHugo Sure, [check it out](https://i.imgur.com/jmdmMLb.png)

Comment: Your pivot of the rect still seems to be set to `0.5`, `0.5` .. try setting it to `y = 1`